# Is it good to use the Http DELETE verb to define a REST API that delete a single specific object?

Tags: rest, web-services, http, restful-architecture, http-verbs

I am implementing some REST APIs and I have a doubt about what HTTP verb should I use to implement an API that remove a single record from my DB

I thought that I should use the **DELETE** method but reading here:
http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

Reading the **DELETE** verb defintion I can read:

> 405 (Method Not Allowed), unless you want to delete the whole
>   collection—not often desirable.

So it seems to me that I have to use **DELETE** when I delete the whole collection and not a single element. Or it fit also the use case in which I am deleting a specific object (passing the ID of this object into my URL)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have misunderstood the content of the link you posted.

The [`DELETE`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) HTTP method can be used to remove a *single resource* or a *collection of resources*.

However, in most of situations, you don't want to allow the client to remove the *entire* collection, so you return a `405` status code indicating that the [`DELETE`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) method is not allowed in the collection URL.

---

In more practical terms, consider that you have a collection of customers mapped to `/customers`.

A `GET` request to such URL will return a representation of this collection. A `DELETE` request to such URL will delete all customers from your application. It's very likely you don't want that, so you return `405` to indicate that deleting all customers at once is not allowed. In the other hand, you want to allow the client to delete a single customer by performing a `DELETE` request to a URL that locates a single customer, such as `/customers/{id}`.

If the request succeeds, consider one of the following status codes, as defined in the RFC 7231:

> If a `DELETE` method is successfully applied, the origin server SHOULD
> send a `202` (Accepted) status code if the action will likely succeed
> but has not yet been enacted, a `204` (No Content) status code if the
> action has been enacted and no further information is to be supplied,
> or a `200` (OK) status code if the action has been enacted and the
> response message includes a representation describing the status.